# ValidationException Exception Description: Cannot acquire data source [jdbc/MyDataBase]

Tags: java, jdbc, netbeans, glassfish

I've googled like crazy, but I am not locating what is going wrong using java persistence.

I am using glassfish 4.1.1.  NetBeans 8.1.  Glassfish is integrated with netbeans and the Server and JDBC resources all show up in the Windows->Services area.

persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="testDB" transaction-type="JTA">       
       <jta-data-source>jdbc/MyDataBase</jta-data-source>
       <class>person.Person</class>
       <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>   
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

GlassFish domain.xml entry for the Connection Pool and Resource

```
<jdbc-resource pool-name="MyDataBase" object-type="system-all" jndi-name="jdbc/MyDataBase"></jdbc-resource>
<jdbc-connection-pool driver-classname="java.sql.Driver" ping="true" datasource-classname="org.postgresql.Driver" name="MyDataBase" res-type="java.sql.Driver">
      <property name="URL" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/testDB"></property>
      <property name="connectionAttributes" value=";create=true"></property>
      <property name="user" value="*****"></property>
      <property name="password" value="****"></property>
      <property name="portNumber" value="5432"></property>
      <property name="databaseName" value="testDB"></property>
      <property name="serverName" value="localhost"></property>
</jdbc-connection-pool>
```

The Pool pings fine from the Glassfish Admin GUI, so I am pretty sure it's there.

My Java Objects:
Class with Entity Manager:

```
package person;

import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;

/**
 *
 * @author jameszeigler
 */
@Named(value = "personCreator")
@RequestScoped
public class PersonCreator {

     private Person person;

     /**
      * Creates a new instance of PersonCreator
      */
     public PersonCreator() {
     }

     public void setPersonValues(){
          person = new Person();
          person.setAge(10);
          person.setFirstName("James");
          person.setLastName("Zeigler");
     }

     public String getPersonValues(){
          return "Test";
     }

     public void persistPerson(){
      EntityManagerFactory emfactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory( "testDB" );

      EntityManager entitymanager = emfactory.createEntityManager( );
      entitymanager.getTransaction( ).begin( );

      setPersonValues();

      entitymanager.persist( person );
      entitymanager.getTransaction( ).commit( );

      entitymanager.close( );
      emfactory.close( );
     }

}
```

And the Entity Class:

```
package person;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

/**
 *
 * @author jameszeigler
 */
@Entity
public class Person implements Serializable {

     // Data Members //
     private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
     @Id
     @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
     private Long id;
     @Column(name="firstName")
     private String firstName;
     @Column(name="lastName")
     private String lastName;
     @Column(name="age")
     private int age;


     // Methods //
     public Long getId() {
          return id;
     }

     public void setId(Long id) {
          this.id = id;
     }

     public void setFirstName(String firstName){
          this.firstName = firstName;
     }

     public String getFirstName(){
          return firstName;
     }

     public void setLastName(String lastName){
          this.lastName = lastName;
     }

     public String getLastName(){
          return lastName;
     }

     public void setAge(int age){
          this.age = age;
     }

     public int getAge(){
          return age;
     }

     @Override
     public int hashCode() {
          int hash = 0;
          hash += (id != null ? id.hashCode() : 0);
          return hash;
     }

     @Override
     public boolean equals(Object object) {
          // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
          if (!(object instanceof Person)) {
               return false;
          }
          Person other = (Person) object;
          if ((this.id == null && other.id != null) || (this.id != null && !this.id.equals(other.id))) {
               return false;
          }
          return true;
     }

     @Override
     public String toString() {
          return "person.Person[ id=" + id + " ]";
     }

}
```

I swear this should work but I get the exception in testing:

```
    javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-7060] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.1.v20150605-31e8258): 
org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException Exception Description: 
Cannot acquire data source [jdbc/MyDataBase]. Internal Exception: javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'jdbc/MyDataBase' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory,
 java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming} [Root exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: MyDataBase not found]
```

The server has this as a resource, am I doing this wrong?  I thought I might need to establish a connection rather than creating an Entity Manager?  There is not another server running currently.  I feel like I am missing something very simple, but I am not sure what it is.

Comment: what's your client? are you deploying this as web application in glassfish, or trying to access from outside glassfish ?
If you are running outside glassfish environment, make sure you have glassfish extras jars 
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.extras/glassfish-embedded-all -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.extras</groupId>
    <artifactId>glassfish-embedded-all</artifactId>
    <version>3.2-b06</version>
</dependency>

Comment: Also, since its eclipselink, did you try adding this line

<property name="eclipselink.target-server" value="SunAS9"/>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had to come back to this one.  I seemed to have solved the issue by switching from Galssfish 4.1 over to Payara.  Glassfish 4.1 apparently has issues with JDBC resources and Connection Pools.  AND I totally incorrectly configured my NetBeans.  NetBeans comes with its own GlassFish installation so Instead of using the GlassFish server I had installed and Configured, it was using its own and had no idea what jdbc pool I was talking about.

I was able to figure that out after getting errors of shutting down the GlassFish domains and getting errors of Ports being in-use.  I finally realized I had two running instances of the Server.  The one I downloaded and installed, and the one NetBeans was running as well.

It was a good learning experience to make sure I configured NetBeans to either use the installed server for local testing ( easier ) or make sure any configurations I make in my local domain.xml that I copied over into my NetBeans install ( less easy ).